# Creating a wizard in Angular 2 - responsibility of data changes

Tags: javascript, angular, software-design

I'm working on an "Advertisement creation wizard"

The wizard is supposed to help the user create an ad, it's composed of 6 different steps.

In the end only 1 object (`adParams`) will be sent to an API.
This object will contain all the required data for the ad creation process.

[The wizard should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuuy2.png)

Every selection in the steps should make changes in the `adParams` object.
What I'm not sure about is where I should handle the changes that the steps wish to apply to the object.

Should I pass the `adParams` object into the step components by @Input and edit the same object directly from all?

Should I emit change events from every step to their parent (the wizard) for it to edit things on it's own?

My main concern is bad growth of the wizard code, leading to too much bulk in one file (in case the wizard itself is the one to make all the changes by listening to outputs from it's children)

Thank you

Comment: have a different components for each step,keep each step's data in redux.

Comment: I casted a close vote, because to me, this question is "opinion based". Aniway, why don't you use 2 way data-binding with "banana in a box"?

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova Thanks for the reply, could you elaborate please?